# Question on react and express website and updating them

Tags: reactjs, express

I have been trying to figure out how to learn making a website.

Does all blog or a any news website have to be a cms. Then wouldn't all pages be the same. If not how does one update their website when adding new posts. Can I do it only from database?

It seems if its made only on html and css updating it would involve adding new new html page every time?
For example [this website](https://blog.jakoblind.no/), how do they add new articles?

Would you recommend making a blog on react?

Thanks very much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Does all blog or a any news website have to be a cms.***

I will say, yes and no,
You can dynamically add new html page whenever you have new posts, or blog, then you create a new route for each request. It works fine,(and a lot simpler, and less worry about other stuff, learn from there and then you get a taste of how it works, I will always suggest you to go with something easier, start really small, since you are starting to learn) until you have to post a lot of post, which will be troublesome to update the server code each time.
Where you have to do as follow: Update codebase (new route: /get/my-new-blog-123), then deploy your server code whenever you have a new post to the cloud server, eg: google cloud platform, heroku, etc. Which is a lot of work.

Till then, which comes to what you have mentioned, Content Management System, where most blog post is structure properly, such as how to insert a picture, text style, typography, etc. Then this html structure will store in database, the route will likely be /get-post/?article-name

*article-name will be something u can query from database,* then your life will be a lot easier with this.

***Would you recommend making a blog on react?***

Yes, definitely, It is easy to learn, but try not to overwhelm yourself with so many tools, such as formik(form submission), redux(state management), whenever you learn something from a blog, most time you will see this. Which will be quite overwhelming, when you are learning so many stuff at once. Especially, if you are really new to HTML, CSS and javascript.

*Start small, learn fast, then grow.* All the best to you.

Comment: My pleasure, glad that it helps you. If this has answered your question, please mark it as correct, so it can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It’s like when you fill out a form
When you press send or save
It’ll go into the backend which means it’s in the database
And from the back end it’ll render to the front which is the website
I can try to elaborate it more if you want.

And you can make a blog using any framework you are comfortable with 
Or you can just use plain ol HTML Css and JavaScript. 
I think it’s best to start at this before moving to a framework